# PHP OOP: why does self::$$property[$key] not work?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, properties, getter-setter

Is there a way to implement the following PHP class without the foreach loop (and otherwise un-changed)?

```
<?php

class foo {

  private static $_thing = array(
    'kee' => 'valyu'
  );

  public static function fetch($property, $key = '') {
    if (property_exists('foo', $property)) {
      if ($key == '') return self::$$property;
      else {

        # i cannot seem to do self::$$property[$key].

        foreach (self::$$property as $_key => $_value) {
          if ($_key == $key) return $_value;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

}

var_dump(foo::fetch('bad'));            # null
var_dump(foo::fetch('_thing'));         # array(1) { ... }
var_dump(foo::fetch('_thing', 'bad'));  # null
var_dump(foo::fetch('_thing', 'kee'));  # string(5) "valyu"

?>
```

`self::$$property[$key]` gives me "access to undeclared static property: foo::$x" (*x* being the first character in the string value of *$key*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply a quirk of the php parser, there seem to be no way to tell the parse with syntax that you want the variable-variable resolved first and then use the `[]` on it's result instead of the `$property[$key]` first, in one line.

However if you break it into two it will work fine:

```
class foo {

  private static $_thing = array(
    'kee' => 'valyu'
  );  

  public static function fetch($property, $key = '') {
   if (property_exists('foo', $property)) {
      if ($key == '') { 
        return self::$$property;
      } else {
        $prop = self::$$property; // move the result to temporary variable, first part of $$property[$key]
        if (array_key_exists($key, $prop)) { //isset will return false if the key is in fact set to null
            return $prop[$key]; // use it, second part of $$property[$key]
        }   
      }   
    }   
    return null;
  }   
}   

var_dump(foo::fetch('bad'));            // null
var_dump(foo::fetch('_thing'));         // array(1) { ... }
var_dump(foo::fetch('_thing', 'bad'));  // null
var_dump(foo::fetch('_thing', 'kee'));  // string(5) "valyu"
```

### Update:

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796393/dan) kindly pointed out, the `{}` syntax can be used to disambiguate the intent for the parser like this:

```
public static function fetch($property, $key = '') {
  if (property_exists('foo', $property)) {
    if ($key == '') {
      return self::$$property;
    } else if (array_key_exists($key, self::${$property})) {
      return self::${$property}[$key];
    }   
  }   
  return null;
}
```

I've also changed the last return from `false` to `null` so it matches your example's comments.

Comment: Shrug. Well, at least the loop is gone. (Should have thought of this before foreach!) Much appreciated!

Comment: Mh. Haven't tried this but wouldn't `self::${$property}[$x]` work, too? Described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php not for properties but for normal variables. No idea if there's a difference in use here.

Comment: Seem to be working, I've tried adding `{}`s there, but seem like missed the right combination. I've updated the answer

Comment: I seem to remember trying `{}` too. Spooky.